# How to handle the "Unknow ODataVersion 3.0" exception when I use odata4j?

Tags: odata, odata4j

I am studying the odata protocal, and find the odata4j, but when I follow the Consumers Example, an exception occurred, "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown ODataVersion 3.0". I debug it and found the odata4j is not supported odata version 3. My question is how can I fix it, or how can I use odata4j? Can I change something to make the version to 2 or 1?? Thank you very much.
By the way, I dowloaded the latest odata4j, which is version 0.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sincere recommendation is to switch to [Apache Olingo](http://olingo.apache.org/) if you would like to implement OData services or clients on the Java platform. The only reason is that OData4J hasn't been updated for more than a year and is not currently supported or maintained. Apache Olingo, on the other hand, is been actively contributed by SAP, Microsoft, and many others. Thus, there are also more samples and documentations there.

Comment: It's very helpful. I am confusing why the Odata4j declare supporting v3 but not finish it. And now I get the reason. I will head for olingo. Thanks.

Comment: @jason What Java OData library did you end up using that supports v3.0 OData standard? I also found out that Apache Olingo *also* does NOT support version 3.0 of the OData Spec.. it appears Olingo only formally supported v2.0 and v4.0, and *never* worked with v3.0 other then a short lived Beta that was killed fast.